# Use Angular to get the URL parameters coming in from another site?

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading the prior questions on this topic and nothing seems to be working for me.

My page is called from an *external* application that is passing something like this:

```
http://MySite/index.html?CompanyId=4000&ActionType=Reservation
```

I need to read the CompanyId and ActionType from this.

I *can't* use the routing parameters because the parameters are *before* any routing information is added to the URL.

I've tried both of these ... and y returns true?

```
    var x = $location.search('CompanyId');
    var y = $location.search().CompanyId;
```

My module configuration is defined like this:

```
// Defining a new module
var module = angular.module("aaa", ["ui.bootstrap","ngRoute"]);

module.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/displaySizes", {
            templateUrl: "views/displaySizes.html",
            controller: "displaySizesController"
        })
        .when("/collectCustomerInfo", {
            templateUrl: "views/collectCustomerInfo.html",
            controller: "collectCustomerInfoCtrl"
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/displaySizes"
        })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

To clarify ... what I have is something this:

```
    http://example.com?companyId=7/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
```

So the parameter I am trying to read is BEFORE the # path. It seems that the $location.search is only searching the portion of the path after the #? Is there a way to get the companyId parameter (without writing all of the parsing code)?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use the routing parameters because the parameters are before any routing information is added to the URL." - these params looks like _the_ routing information for the URL. Also, remember you can always just hook before angular (for example, while in the `<head>` section before you include the angular library and access document.location yourself.

Answer (score 1):

$location.search() returns the query parameters in a parsed JSON object - so it returns only the values after the '?' in the url.

The following is one solution to get the companyId parameter. It does not use Angular and does use "parsing code", but it seems simple enough.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var parts = url.split("/");
var firstUrlTerm = parts[0];
var firstTermParts = firstUrlTerm.split("=");
var firstTermValue = firstTermValue[1];
```

Comment: My fault ... I had a typo in the example string. Please see the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an Angular service that parsed the URL.

```
// IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
(function () {
angular.module("aaa.services", [])
.factory('aaaInformationService', ["$rootScope",
    function($rootScope,$location) {
        var siteInformation = {};

        // Properties
        siteInformation.companyId=getUrlVars()["CompanyId"];
        siteInformation.connectionType = getUrlVars()["ConnectionType"];

        // Support functions
        function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = {};
            var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            });
            return vars;
        }
        return siteInformation;
    }])
}());
```

I was never able to get the $location to work.